# Unity get sprite from Image

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get sprite from Image in Unity but I am facing an issue. I am using this code:

```
void Start () {
     Sprite sprite = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite;

     if (sprite == null) {
            Debug.Log ("NULL");
        } else {
            Debug.Log ("NOT NULL");
        }
}
```

If the sprite is empty, it does not recognize as "null". Why? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a function to get around it. Basically this function checks if the "Source Image" is null, then it throws an "UnassignedReferenceException". If anyone needs:

```
public int CheckReference (Object reference) {
        int myRef = 1;

        try {
            var blarf = reference.name;
        } catch (MissingReferenceException) // General Object like GameObject/Sprite etc
        {
            myRef = 0;
            Debug.LogError ("The provided reference is missing!");
        } catch (MissingComponentException) // Specific for objects of type Component
        {
            myRef = 0;
            Debug.LogError ("The provided reference is missing!");
        } catch (UnassignedReferenceException) // Specific for unassigned fields
        {
            Debug.LogWarning ("The provided reference is null!");
            myRef = 0; //My image is null
        }

        return myRef;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If your component is an [Image](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-Image.html) then the right property is `Source Image`, but if you are using a [Sprite Renderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteRenderer.html) component then the property is `Sprite`.

The difference between the 2 components are simple, `Image` component is used for UI elements and the `SpriteRenderer` is used for the world space environment.

You can read more about the 2 components through there documentations.

Comment: If OP was using a `SpriteRenderer` then OP would already get an exception thrown since `GetComponent<Image>` would already return `null` ...

Comment: Also wouldn't be better if he cached the component and then try to get the sprite property as a best practice?

Comment: It would but in this case it is only done once anyway